# Ethereum transaction with low gas

Tags: ether

I made a payment but used very low 0.000000021 Ether (21 Gwei). I cannot repeat transaction becuse coins already deducted from my account.
Transaction is still pending.

Can I do something about it? Or I just need to wait? Will it come eventually?

Comment: See also https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/23794/would-a-minimal-gas-price-tx-ever-be-mined and https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/18736/are-pending-transactions-dropped-and-reinstated